# Retry events in stripe after enabling the webhook

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have implemented a payment module in which there is a Stripe webhook for listening and handling the events that are triggered by Stripe. Once the webhook on our server is in `Listening` status, everything works fine. sometimes our server may have a network or service problem that leads to setting the webhook's status to `disabled`. after re-activating the webhook on the server by stopping and starting its service, I want to get all of the events that I've not received automatically.

For more information, I should say that I started the stripe listening service like below:

`nohup ./stripe listen --forward-to https://example.com/stripe/webhook &`

Could you please help me to solve it?

Comment: You would have to check with Stripe, whether they _offer_ such a re-sending of failed webhooks ...

Comment: Stripe does have retry logic for failed webhook events [1]. The behavior differs for livemode and testmode. I'd recommend reading through the link as it explains what you can expect in terms of delivery attempts and retries. There's also an API to query missed events in-case the events are past retry period. 

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#retry-logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really doubtful ***if sometimes, your server may have a network or service problem that leads to setting the webhook's status to disabled***.

I think the problem is because of **Stripe itself** but not because of you.

It seems like you want your webhook to get retries from **Stripe** when your webhook returns **400 http response** or timed out to response **200 http response** to **Stripe** for **some particular event types "payment_intent.created", "payment_intent.succeeded", "charge.succeeded", "checkout.session.completed"** etc.

From my one week experiments, at least with **Stripe Checkout**, in **"test" mode**, I found that **Stripe** doesn't send any retries to my webhook **most of the time** even if I intentionally return **400 http response** or timed out to response **200 http response** to **Stripe**.

And, one by one, I returned **400 http response** for **4 event types "payment_intent.created", "payment_intent.succeeded", "charge.succeeded" and "checkout.session.completed"**, then waited for the retry from **Stripe**. Finally, **Stripe** sent **"setup_intent.created"** for **all 4 event types**. So, your webhook will be able to get **only one event type "setup_intent.created"** as a retry.

Actually, I asked **Stripe support** about all what I mentioned above **spending more than 3 or 4 hours** but they don't even know much about **Stripe** which means **horrible support eating time**. So, you better solve any problems about **Stripe** yourself because you know **Stripe** super much more than them. Or just use other payment services.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (2024-02-23) [docs](https://docs.stripe.com/webhooks#behaviors) regarding the retries say:

> ## Event delivery behaviors
>
> This section helps you understand different behaviors to expect regarding how Stripe sends events to your webhook endpoint.
>
> ### Retry behavior
>
> **In live mode**, Stripe attempts to deliver a given event to your webhook endpoint for up to 3 days with an exponential back off. In the Events section of the Dashboard, you can view when the next retry will occur.
>
> **In test mode**, Stripe retries three times over a few hours. You can manually retry transmitting individual events to your webhook endpoint after this time using the Events section of the Dashboard. You can also query for missed events to reconcile the data over any time period.
>
> The automatic retries still continue, even if you manually retry transmitting individual webhook events to a given endpoint and the attempt is successful.